# Airflow docker "Module not found" Selenium

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, airflow

I am currently trying to run an Airflow DAG which uses the selenium package locally with docker. I have successfully pip-installed the selenium and web driver packages in the docker container however when I am trying to run the dag I receive this error from the airflow logs and a similar one on the web console. I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 326, in parse
    loader.exec_module(new_module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/ytscrapper.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Comment: Can you run a `pip freeze` in a `bash operator`  and verify that selenium is installed in the container?